# How to fix bounds/change variable bounds in macro BranchCallback? C++

Tags: c++, callback, branch, cplex

In the code below I'm trying to create a branch callback using the CPLEX macro `ILOBRANCHCALLBACK2` where I'm chosing the ways of fixing some varables bounds. But when doing the fixing I'm getting an access violation error when reading some space. Could someone tell me the right way of doing this? Do I have to do the make branch for all the variables or will the branchcallback do it itself?

```
ILOBRANCHCALLBACK2(simetria, const Instance&, instance, const IloNumVarMatrix&, X) {
    vector<coordenates> F_zeros;
    vector<coordenates> F_ones;
    vector<int> a;
    a.resize(instance.getNbClients());
    a[0] = 0;
    coordenates first;
    first.x = 0;
    first.y = 0;
    F_ones.push_back(first);

    // Je verifie s'il y a deja des variables fixées
    for(int i = 1; i < instance.getNbClients() - 1; ++i) {
        for(int j = 1; j < instance.getNbVehicles() - 1; ++j) {
            if(getUB(X[i][j]) <= 0.001) {
                coordenates obj;
                obj.x = i;
                obj.y = j;
                F_zeros.push_back(obj);
            }

            if(getLB(X[i][j]) >= 0.99) {
                coordenates obj;
                obj.x = i;
                obj.y = j;
                F_ones.push_back(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // Je vais construir mon a.
    for(int k = 1; k < instance.getNbClients() - 1; k++) {
        // Zero setting
        if(a[k - 1] == instance.getNbVehicles() - 1 || findInVector(F_zeros, k, a[k - 1] + 1)) {
            a[k] = a[k - 1];
            coordenates obj;
            obj.x = k;
            obj.y = a[k - 1];

        } else {
            a[k] = a[k - 1] + 1;
            coordenates obj;
            obj.x = k;
            obj.y = a[k - 1] + 1;
        }
    }

    // Je mets a jour le F_zero a partir de a
    for(int k = 1; k < instance.getNbClients() - 1; k++) {
        for(int p = 1; p < instance.getNbVehicles() - 1; p++) {
            if(p > a[k]) {
                coordenates obj;
                obj.x = k;
                obj.y = p;
                F_zeros.push_back(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // je fixe tout ce qui est en  F_zero en zero (Changer les bornnes)
    for(int i = 0; i < F_zeros.size(); i++) {
        int a = F_zeros[i].x;
        int b = F_zeros[i].y;
        X[a][b].setUB(0);
        // X[F_zeros[i].x][F_zeros[i].y].setBounds(0, 0);
        // makeBranch(X[F_zeros[i].x][F_zeros[i].y], 0, IloCplex::BranchUp, getBestObjValue());
        // makeBranch(X[F_zeros[i].x][F_zeros[i].y], 0, IloCplex::BranchDown, getBestObjValue());
    }
```

Comment: I see a function, no macro...

Comment: You could make your code more self-explanatory and thereby increase your chances, by translating everything to English.

Comment: ... and it's not even a complete function. Make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ... and it would benefit from some consistent indentation.

Comment: @GorAsatryan Your edit is very small, be careful with that. However, I approve because even a small typo (or language-misselection) like that is really distracting in a title.

Comment: @Estefânia Moura When asking question about something as specific as CPLEX, make use of the tags. I added the `cplex` tag to the question. It will hopefully attract people who knows this framework.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I’m new in here. I will try to do better next time

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a model while it is being solved (for example, see the *Note* in the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks_basic/22_cb_interface.html)). As you have found out, this can result in a segfault. Thus, you cannot use the `setUB` method in your callback.

As you probably know (based on the code you have commented out), you can use the [makeBranch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_BranchCallbackI.html#method_makeBranch) method, which:

> instructs the invoking IloCplex object how to create a subnode from
>   the current node by specifying new, tighter bounds for a set of
>   variables.

Comment: I did that and I found out that Makebranch only acepts IloNumVarArray as argument, and my variable it's a IloNumVarMatrix.

Comment: I assume you have the following in your code: `typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> IloNumVarMatrix`. So, `X[i]` should give you a `IloNumVarArray`. Is there a reason you can't work with this?